# React native how to manage list of inputs

Tags: react-native

I wrote an api it return jsondata and limit. I'm creating inputlist in scrollview by lenght of limit.In creation i set the values to input comes from jsondata. Jsondata is may content 0-30 value.
I just gotta how to save this as array.

Here's my code it gives value to input if not undefined

Also do i need onchange for input component for input

```
export  class DataListFor extends Component { 
    constructor() {   super();
      this.state = {
        dataSource: [],
        limit: 30,
        };   }
     
  
    componentDidMount() {
      const url = "https://sssaaaaaexample.herokuapp.com/getExample";
      
      this.setState({
        dataSource: this.props.route.params.list,
        limit: this.props.route.params.limit,
      })        
    }
  
  
    render() {
      var itemList = [];
      var data=this.state.dataSource;      
    for(let i = 0; i < this.state.limit; i++){
  
    if(data[i]==undefined)
    { 
      itemList.push(      
        <View key = {i}>
          <View>
          <TextInput
        style={{ height: "auto",width:'auto', alignItems: 'center',
        fontSize: 20,borderColor:'white',borderWidth:1}}
        
        
      />
          </View>
        
        </View>
      )
    }
    else{
      
      itemList.push(      
        <View key = {i}>
          <View>
          <TextInput
        style={{ height: "auto",width:'auto',borderColor:'white',borderWidth:1}}
        
        value={data[i].text}
      />
          </View>
        
        </View>
      )
    }
        
    }
      return ( 
  
        <View style={{
          flex: 1,
          flexDirection: 'column',
          justifyContent: 'space-between',
        }}>
          <View  >
            <Text style={appStyles.listHeader}> To-do</Text>       
            
  
          </View>
  
          <ScrollView style={appStyles.scrollView}>

          { itemList }
          </ScrollView>
        

  <Button
        title="Save"
        onPress={() => console.log("saved")}
      />
        </View>
      )
  
    }
  }
```

Comment: I gotta post it to and api endpoint